# Sujud Sahw for mistaking in a part of a surah during salah

Tags: salat, fiqh, practical-islam

I was the imam for a Maghrib prayer and while reciting an ayah from *al-Kahf* I ended it with *"Muslim"* instead of *"walam yaj'al lahu iwaja"*

Then I asked my ma'mum to do Sujud Sahw, but they rejected the idea of doing so.

But I performed it anyway but am now afraid that I have sinned not only on my behalf but also of my ma'mum. Did I do the right thing? Have I sinned?

Comment: What's "ma'mum"?

Comment: "Ma'mum" are those who are following (the imam in a prayer)

Comment: I'm not sure: But you didn't have to do sujud sahw as explained by Chlebta. But i guess your ma'mums did a sin as they have to follow you if you do sujud sahw! see also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25189/left-one-ayat-in-the-middle-of-surah-in-salat/27673#27673

Answer (score -1):

If you make mistake in Sourat( NOT FATIHA) recitation you don't have to make sujid shaw because the sourat after Fatiha is `Moustahaba` not `Rokn`.
Also take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNDIFyM-nZU) and [this](http://www.shafiifiqh.com/how-is-sujud-al-sahw-prostration-of-forgetfulness-made/)